# How to trim, pad and append specific positional data at end of the file using sed in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting, trim

I am looking for command using sed which will pick specified positional data, trim spaces from both ends, check if length is <15 then append leading 0s to make it 15 and append that at the of the line.

Input: echo "123456 890 2345"

positions: 7 to 11

So data is " 890 "

output: "123456<5 spaces>2345000000000000890"

Comment: That might help for part of the job with bash. `s=7; e=11; x="123456 890 2345"; echo ${x:$s-1:$e-$s+1}`

Answer (score 0):

You have somewhat limited the advanced shell features that could be used (e.g. sting indexes, etc.) by tagging your question `sh` (meaning POSIX shell compliant). `sed` is a wonderful stream editor, and has great line range selection capability, but is limited in character index selection ability. `awk` is another alternative with `awk '{print substr...}'` which can handle the job without much of an issue.

POSIX shell can also do the job using the traditional `expr ...` substring, length and index tools, employing character classes for whitespace removal. Given you tagged your question `sh`, let's look at a method for handling the substring extraction, replacement with spaces and appending a zero-padded 15-char representation of the substring.

Below the script is well-commented inline, but essentially gets the length of the input, the indexes of the positions for extracting the substring (noting POSIX shell indexes from `1` not `0`), builds a string of spaces to replace the extracted substring, trims leading/trailing spaces from the substring, and then puts it all back together, treating the trimmed substring as an integer using `printf` to append the zero padded `15-character` wide subtring to the end, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

str="123456 890 2345"   # input
s=7                     # start positon
e=11                    # end position
spc=                    # spaces string (unset)
i=0                     # counter

strlen=$(expr length "$str")                    # input length
sub=$(expr substr "$str" "$s" "$((e - s + 1))") # extract ' 890 '
slen=$(expr length "$sub")                      # length sub

while [ "$i" -lt "$slen" ]  # build spaces replacement
do
    spc="$spc "
    ((i++))
done

# get non-space start index in sub to trim leading spaces
# (adjust character class as required)
sidx=$(expr index "$sub" "[0123456789]")

# if start index > 1 extract substring beginning at sidx
((sidx > 1)) && sub=$(expr substr "$sub" "$sidx" $((slen - sidx + 1)))

# get index of any space at end
eidx=$(expr index "$sub" "[ ]")

# if end index > 1 extract substring up to eidx
((eidx > 1)) && sub=$(expr substr "$sub" "1" $((eidx - 1)))

# build result string
res="$(expr substr "$str" "1" $((s - 1)))"  # first s-1 chars in str
res="$res$spc"                              # append spaces
# append final characters after e in str
res="$res$(expr substr "$str" $((e + 1)) $((strlen - e)))"
res="$res$(printf "%015d" "$sub")"  # use printf to format 0-padded sub
# (note, if not decimal, use loop to append zeros)

echo "input : '$str'"
echo "result: '$res'"  # output final result
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh substrapp.sh
input : '123456 890 2345'
result: '123456     2345000000000000890'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/./&\n/11;T;s//\n&/7;s/(\n\s*(\S+)\s*\n.*)/\1\n\2/;:a;ta;s/^([^\n]*\n *)[^ \n]/\1 /;ta;s/\n//;s///;:b;tb;/\n.{15}$/s/\n//;t;s/\n/&0/;bb' file
```

Append a newline to the 11th character. If the substitution was successful carry on, otherwise print the current line and no further processing of the line is carried out. Prepend the 7th character with a newline. Using substitution and back references, append a newline followed by the space-clipped portion of the substring of the original line from character 7 to character 11. Using a loop replace the original substring with spaces and then remove the newline markers. Using a loop prepend `0`'s to the appended space-clipped substring to make the new string 15 characters in overall length. Finally remove the newline delimiter and print the resulting string.